# Linux kernel architecture support timeline

Tags: linux, kernel

I would love if someone could precisely spell dates of introduction of each architecture (x86, alpha, sparc, arm, etc.) support in Linux kernel.

I found this illustration for Debian Linux distribution:

[image]

However, I need data for plain Linux kernel, not Debian Linux.

Comment: Those directly apply to kernel support as well.  It could be that Debian lagged somewhat behind adopting new architectures, but  given what I know about x86 and Alpha, it looks about the same.

Comment: @wallyk yes, what you said is valuable info for me, how ever I need complete data, there are some archs that linux kernel supports, and  debian does not

Comment: Why do you ask? I guess that at some early stage, the Linux kernel was runnable on some architecture, but not much user-land software. Then, what is the point of your question? To be usable you need a working Linux kernel and some working user-land. And the user-land part depends upon why you want to use Linux: a router with some embedded Linux needs a different user-land software than a desktop

Comment: I am putting together a research project where this info is relevant. So, it is not some hardware device or similar. Also, to answer your second question, I am interested in Linux kernel specifically, not userland/Linux as a complete OS. @BasileStarynkevitch

Answer (score 1):

**Debian Family Tree**

I think you wanted to see this,

[Direct link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/DebianFamilyTree1210.svg)

[image]

Comment: This is for the Debian distribution, not the kernel per se.